# How create RSpec test to test an Array of invalid emails using all matcher

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to make a test for an email validation pattern, to this I create a array with all invalid emails and try use `not_to all` matcher to test this.

```rb
       context 'when invalid email' do
          let(:invalid_emails) do
            [
              'plainaddress',
              '#@%^%#$@#$@#.com',
              '@example.com',
              'Joe Smith <email@example.com>',
              'email.example.com',
              'email@example@example.com',
              '.email@example.com',
              'email.@example.com',
              'email..email@example.com',
              'あいうえお@example.com',
              'email@example.com (Joe Smith)',
              'email@example',
              'email@-example.com',
              'email@example.web',
              'email@111.222.333.44444',
              'email@example..com',
              'Abc..123@example.com'
            ]
          end
    
          it 'no match' do
            expect(invalid_emails).not_to all(match(helper.html_validation_pattern))
          end
        end
```

but I receive this error

```
 NotImplementedError:
       `expect().not_to all( matcher )` is not supported.
```

Exist another way to do this?

Comment: if nothing else, you can just use `each` and then run the check on them individually. Maybe there's a way to use `all`, you could also maybe use the block form of `all`.

Comment: @maxpleaner yep, this is true. Isn't more beauty but work Thanks Max =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#none?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-none-3F) with regexp

```
expect(invalid_emails.none?(/regexp/)).to be true
```

or just iterate array

```
invalid_emails.each { |email| expect(email).not_to match /regexp/ }
```